# gettimeofday causing high httpd cpu usage

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, centos6, cpu-usage, ioncube

Im running a php script with ioncube/zend.

All Cores are at 100% and the system begins to accumulate load.

All httpd processes are in R (reading status) and it looks like they are reading on something. I have to restart apache to fix the problem temporarily.

also domain.com/server-status does not show any php script with high cpu usage.

PHP 5.6.29 (cli)

Ioncube loader version 6.0.8

Apache/2.2.15

```
top - 04:25:25 up  1:33,  1 user,  load average: 6.15, 6.27, 4.63
Tasks: 256 total,   6 running, 236 sleeping,  13 stopped,   1 zombie
Cpu(s): 96.0%us,  3.7%sy,  0.0%ni,  0.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.1%si,     0.2%st
Mem:   8191292k total,  2068300k used,  6122992k free,    28088k buffers
Swap:        0k total,        0k used,        0k free,   940004k cached

PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
1534 apache    20  0  492m  23m 8176 R 79.1  0.3   7:43.32 httpd
1399 apache    20  0  492m  22m 7596 R 78.5  0.3  13:33.11 httpd
22154 apache   20  0  492m  22m 7556 R 77.1  0.3  13:27.89 httpd
1339 apache    20  0  492m  23m 8328 R 74.5  0.3   9:04.79 httpd
```

When i run strace -fcp 1534 for 10 second i got 285273 calls on gettimeofday

```
[root@centos-8gb-lon1-01 ~]# strace -fcp 1534 
Process 1534 attached    

% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00    0.000823           0    285273           gettimeofday
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00    0.000823                285273           total
```

Also strace -p 1534 i got

```
gettimeofday({1484299975, 598212}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1484299975, 598255}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1484299975, 598318}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1484299975, 598362}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1484299975, 598401}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1484299975, 598442}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1484299975, 598484}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1484299975, 598524}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1484299975, 598564}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1484299975, 598603}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1484299975, 598640}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1484299975, 598677}, NULL) = 0
```

Any idea how to fix this?
Thanks

Comment: Are you using mod_status with ExtendedStatus on?

Comment: @ezra-s yes but mod_status its not the problem, i activate mod_status after i had this problem.

Comment: The reason I ask is because mod_status calls that function twice per request if ExtendedStatus is on. That would explain the amount, but since you say it's something else...